# Can't get data from getters in router. [Vuex, quasar]

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, quasar-framework, quasar

I want to get date form getters in router. 
I have 2 modules in my store:

```
export default function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
const Store = new Vuex.Store({
 modules: {
   customers,
   auth
 },
 namespaced: true,
 strict: process.env.DEV
})

  return Store
}
```

And this is my auth/index.js

```
import state from "./state";
import * as getters from "./getters"
import * as mutations from "./mutations"
import * as actions from "./actions"

export default {
 namespaced: true,
 state,
 mutations,
 actions,
 getters
}
```

I want to check if my user is authenthcated so before go to component I want to check it.

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: () => import('pages/Index.vue'),
    beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated()
  },
```

Now in router/index.js I declare my function

```
export function ifAuthenticated(to, from, next){
console.log(store.auth); //undefined
if (store.auth.getters.isAuthenticated) {
  next();
  return;
}
next("/login");
};
```

How can I call my getters to return value or how can I call my store for auth module?

Comment: What about console.log(this.$store.auth) ?

Comment: it print undefined

Comment: console.log(this.$store)?

Comment: the same result

Comment: You should dynamically add this route in a place where there is an access to a store and define a route like this: 
`beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => { 
   ifAuthenticated(to, from ,next, this.store) // add fourth param 'store' to the ifAuthenticated
}
`

Answer (score 2):

That would be:

```
this.$store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities I would suggest trying.
First of all, take a look at this answer ([How to access the getter from another vuex module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45999623/how-to-access-the-getter-from-another-vuex-module)).

I would try:

```js
this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated()
store.getters.isAuthenticated()
// don’t forget the ()
```

And then try adding RootGetters and test the same pieces again.
If that doesn’t work you can try namespacing ([What exactly is namespacing of modules in vuex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792212/what-exactly-is-namespacing-of-modules-in-vuex))

```js
store.getters[‘auth/isAuthenticated’]
```

Or you can try setting up an enum with your authGetters in your store

```js
export enum authGetters {
  IS_AUTHENTICATED = 'isAuthenticated'
}

store.getters[authGetters.IS_AUTHENTICATED]
```